# Symfony2, no route found and defaults

Tags: symfony, routes

Simple question but I have issues with it.
We have simple route

```
profile_api_info:
    pattern:  /api/info/{apiID}
    defaults: { _controller: SiteProfileBundle:Api:info, apiID: null}
```

When we use such url as

```
http://some.site/api/info/123
```

we'll get proper result of controller.
But when we use this one

```
http://some.site/api/info/
```

we'll have an error, why?

```
No route found for "GET /profile/api/info/"
```

We'll have already setuped 'defaults' for our 'apiID' but symfony2 says that no route. Can someone suggest how to deal with it? I want routes

```
http://some.site/api/info
http://some.site/api/info/
```

have the same controller as

```
http://some.site/api/info/123
```

but with 'apiID' = null or false, no matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

**Option 1:**
Pass your default parameter.

```
profile_api_info:
    pattern:  /api/info/{apiID}
    defaults: { _controller: SiteProfileBundle:Api:info, apiID: null}
```

However you will not be able to have trailing `/`. 
This would be correct: `http://some.site/api/info`
This would be **incorrect** `http://some.site/api/info/`

**Option 2:**
set up an additional route.
(*This would be my preference.*)

```
profile_api_info_woId:
    pattern:  /api/info/
    defaults: { _controller: SiteProfileBundle:Api:info}
```

In your controller make sure set the default for `$apiID` to null.

```
public function infoAction($apiID = null){...}
```

Using two routes with one controller method should work for all of the following urls:

```
http://some.site/api/info
http://some.site/api/info/
http://some.site/api/info/123
```

Comment: it's not the solution I'm searching but i think there are not others, i search everywhere =\

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this multiple times and clearing the cache so that Symfony can rebuild the route definitions usually fixes the issue.

Syntax and everything looks correct. However, the route with the trailing slash (`http://some.site/api/info/`) won't work but `http://some.site/api/info` should.

Comment: I clear the cache - still the same. :( I'm using create by composer standard vendor version 2.3.

Comment: I know, I am interesting only if 'apiID' is empty at all. Because of that slash, route not found.

Comment: And yes I know that we can create specific route for 'base + slash' but it's not the solution. :(

Comment: Then your issue is somewhere else because your route definition is correct to match `http://some.site/api/info/123` and `http://some.site/api/info`. Symfony docs clearly state that the routes with optional parameters will not work with the trailing slash.